# D3.js Messing Up URL "%20" space character

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, character-encoding

I'm using D3 for listing a number of people along with there photos. We have there photos stored via a URL and I have that URL coming through as a field in the data. Every 10 seconds, I am calling an update function that updates the data in case new people get added or removed to/from the list.

I'm using the encodedURIComponent to encode the incoming url because some photos are store with spaces and some are not. This function is doing it's job. The issue seems to be happening when I append the url and the dynamic fileName together.

It works fine for most data elements, but on a few it screws my URL up. It only occurs on transition. The error will be something like this:

```
GET http://myUrl/images/employees/firstName%20LastNamepng
```

In this case, it removed the "." before the png. Here's another case:

```
GET http://myUrl/images/employees/firstName%6.279540991999999lastName.png
```

In this case, it came up with some random # to replace the 20%.

During the transition, I'm setting the attr to this:

```
"xlink:href": function (d) {
     return "http://myURL/images/employees/" + d.encodedUrl;
}
```

Any idea??

Comment: seems may be your back-end problem when you are processing the path? did you encode your string after combined them(url, dynamic file name) ?

Comment: @twxia No, I encode the dynamic string (only the firstName lastName.png) part before this function occurs. I check the encoded string of the data elements that screw up and they are just as they should be. So, the data property "encodedUrl" (which is the dynamic fName and lastName with the .png) is perfect, but it's interpreting it different. (e.g. adding those weird numbers and removing the "." from the png extension

Comment: you'll need to creat a [mcve] I think.